# Fastest way to find the event with most viewers at a given moment?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

**Problem:**

There is a special day, when <=1'000'000 events are hold.

There are <=1'000'000 viewers watching those events (not necessarily the same number).

Special day is divided into <=100'000 moments (every event lasts all day).

Each viewer is watching exactly one event during the special day.

They watch only a chunk of event from moment1 to moment2.

**I/O:**

First, we're given the number of viewers N and the number of moments.

Then, we're given N lines. The i-th line contains three numbers:

M1, M2, E - telling us that the i-th viewer will watch the event E from moment M1 to moment M2 (inclusive).

Then, we get questions. Each question is a number Q. It asks what is the most numerous event at the moment Q. (if there are more than one, the event with the lowest number is returned)

**What is the fast(est) algorithm to answer those questions, given the memory limitations (128MB)?**

Comment: This sounds like a job for an [interval tree.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)

Comment: @JimMischel I'm not sure... could you please elaborate? If I understand correctly, using inteval tree would give me a list of all viewers watching some event at the moment Q. But then, I'd still have to find which event has most viewers, right? Isn't the pessimistic time still >=O(n), then?

Comment: There should be a way to group the data during construction to avoid the O(n) search time. I'd have to give it a bit more thought. The nature of the problem screams "interval tree" to me, though. That's where I'd start looking. But I could be wrong. If I was more sure of it, I'd give an answer rather than just commenting.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest I can think of (now) is to sort the N lines by events. This has complexity O(N log(N)). To answer a question, a single scan over the sorted array of lines is sufficient. This has complexity O(N).

Memory requirements are (assuming 4 byte integers):

- 12 N for the array (and maybe another 6 N for the sort)
- N for storing the result (there can be more than one "winner", just imagine all visit a different event at the same time interval).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, this solution is too slow. I've coded it ( http://pastebin.com/CzYcZNGj ) but most of the tests give me "time limit exceeded" error (also, one answer is wrong, I don't yet know why). Im afraid that the answer time has to be O(logn).

Answer (score 0):

The following solution has complexity O(n log n) to construct the data structure. Each query can be satisfied in O(1).

Create a class, `Viewer` to represent your input lines. That is:

```
class Viewer
    int StartMoment;
    int EndMoment;
    int EventId;
```

Also create a class, `Event`, which contains an event number and its count:

```
class Event
    int Id;
    int Count;
```

Create a dictionary of `Event` instances, keyed by Id. Also create a priority queue (max-heap) of `Event`, ordered by `Count`, descending, and `Id`. Note that the priority queue contains references to items that are in the dictionary. Also, your priority queue must implement *decrease-key*, and *remove* (i.e. remove an arbitrary item) efficiently. Something like Pairing heap is good for this. It's possible with a binary heap, but difficult to implement.

The dictionary is there so that you can easily look up things that are in the priority queue. This makes it very fast, O(1) to locate things in the queue, and makes deleting and re-ordering very fast. Call the dictionary `EventsDict`. The priority queue is `EventsQueue`. Both are initially empty.

Create *another* priority queue, this one of `Viewer` instances, ordered by `EndMoment`. Call it `CurrentViewers`. It, too, is initially empty.

Finally, create an array of `moment-count` `Event` references. This is the output of the algorithm below. Call it `Moments`.

Read the viewer lines into a list of `Viewer` instances. Call it `Viewers`. Sort by `StartMoment` and `EventId`.

Now start going through the `Viewer` lines sequentially.

```
int currentMoment;
for each viewer
{
    Event currentEvent;
    if (viewer.StartMoment > currentMoment)
    {
        // The most viewed event at the current moment is at the top of the CurrentEvents heap
        Moments[currentMoment] = EventsQueue.Peek();

        currentMoment = viewer.StartMoment;
        // remove any viewers that are no longer active, and update the events queue accordingly
        while (CurrentViewers.Peek().EndMoment < currentMoment)
        {
            oldViewer = CurrentViewers.Dequeue();
            currentEvent = EventsDict[oldViewer.EventId];
            EventsQueue.Remove(currentEvent);
            --EventsQueue.Count;
            // if the count goes to 0, remove it from the active list
            // Otherwise re-insert it into the queue
            if (currentEvent.Count == 0)
            {
                EventsDict.Remove(currentEvent.Id);
            }
            else
            {
                EventsQueue.Enqueue(currentEvent);
            }
        }
    }
    if (EventsDict.ContainsKey(viewer.EventId))
    {
        // updates the count and re-inserts the item in the queue
        currentEvent = EventsDict[viewer.EventId];
        EventsQueue.Remove(currentEvent);
        ++currentEvent.Count;
        EventsQueue.Enqueue(currentEvent);
    }
    else
    {
        currentEvent = new Event(viewer.EventId, 1);
        EventsQueue.Enqueue(currentEvent);
    }
    // Add this viewer to the `CurrentViewers` queue
    CurrentViewers.Enqueue(viewer);
}
```

How it works:

The idea here is that we start at the earliest moment that has a viewer, and we keep track of which events are being viewed as we go along. As each viewer record is read, we update the count for the referenced event and add the viewer to the queue so it can be removed when its EndMoment is reached. The EventsQueue is maintained such that the event that currently has the largest number of viewers is always at the top of the heap. That's why we remove and re-add an event every time its count changes. The EventsDict exists only to keep track of which events are currently active.

So let's say we have these five viewers:

```
eventId  startMoment  endMoment
  7          2           7
  1          3           5
  1          3           4
  7          3           5
  7          4           6
```

At the start of the loop, `currentMoment` is set to 2, because that's the starting moment of the first watched event. The first time through the loop, event 7 is added to the events queue and currentViewers queue.

Next time through the loop, the `viewer.StartMoment` is 3, but `currentMoment` is 2. So we have to update the output and then set `currentMoment` to 3. Nothing is removed from the current viewers queue because nothing has an `endMoment` less than 3. Then we add event 1 to the current events queue, and to current viewers.

Next time through the loop (the third item in the list above), we're still at moment 3. We increment the count for event 1 and add re-insert it into the events queue. And the item is added to currentViewers.

Next time, still at moment 3. Increment the count for event 7 and add the viewer to currentViewers.

Last item, we're now at moment 4. At this point, events 1 and 7 both have two viewers. Event 1 has the lower id, so that's the event that gets placed in the output. We also need to remove the third item in the list (event 1 with end moment 4) from the current events queue, and decrement the count for event 1.

Then we set current moment to 4 and increment the count for event 7.

It looks like I left off the last part of the algorithm, which has to empty the queues after all the viewer events are read. So at the end of the loop above, you need to add a bit more code:

```
currentMoment = currentViewers.Peek().EndMoment;
while (currentViewers is not empty)
{
    viewer = currentViewers.Dequeue();
    if (viewer.EndMoment > currentMoment)
    {
        Moments[currentMoment] = EventsQueue.Peek();
        currentMoment = viewer.EndMoment;
    }
    currentEvent = EventsDict[oldViewer.EventId];
    EventsQueue.Remove(currentEvent);
    --EventsQueue.Count;
    // if the count goes to 0, remove it from the active list
    // Otherwise re-insert it into the queue
    if (currentEvent.Count == 0)
    {
        EventsDict.Remove(currentEvent.Id);
    }
    else
    {
        EventsQueue.Enqueue(currentEvent);
    }
}
```

All that code does is make sure to populate the tail end of the Moments array after all the viewers have been read. It's basically a repeat of the code that removes things when an event view goes out of scope, and when the current moment changes.

Let's call the number of viewers N. Sorting the viewer lines is O(N log N). In addition, each viewer is added to the CurrentViewers queue once (O(1)), and removed once (O(log N)). Each time through the loop involves one event being inserted or removed and then re-inserted in the EventsQueue. For worst case analysis, let's say that evey time through the loop involves an O(log n) removal of the item from the EventsQueue.

So we have O(N log N) for the initial sort. O(N) to add items to the CurrentViewers queue. O(N log N) to remove items from CurrentViewers. O(N) to add items to the EventsQueue, and O(N log N) to remove items from the EventsQueue. So construction is:

```
3*(N log N) + 2*N ~ O(N log N)
```

You end up building an array that has the most-watched event at every moment. So an individual query is a simple array lookup, O(1).

With fewer than 1,000,000 viewers and events and fewer than 100,000 moments, this should easily fit into 128 MB. I'd be pretty surprised if it took even half of that.

Comment: Hi :) thanks a lot for answering. I tried implementing Your algorithm, but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/wu2XNYmL The structures (priority queue, dictionary) are probably very inefficient, but for the moment, I just wanted them to function properly (and I think they do - I included a test in the comments). Unfortunately, when I run this program, I get incorrect results (example in the comments). Could You please help me?

Comment: @Jecke: I'm not a C++ programmer, so I can't really say whether your implementations of the priority queues and dictionaries are correct. One thing I did notice is that you're populating the `CurrentViewers` queue and the `EventsQueue` before beginning the main loop. My algorithm says that both of those queues should initially be empty.

Comment: I have some questions, then: You didn't initialize `CurrentMoment`, yet one of the first checks is `if (viewer.StartMoment > currentMoment)` - how should `CurrentMoment` be initialized? If the condition is true, then first thing is `Moments[currentMoment] = EventsQueue.Peek()` - but EventsQueue is empty... And the next command is `while(CurrentViewers.Peek().EndMoment < currentMoment)` - but CurrentViewers is empty too! And if the condition is false, then `CurrentMoment` will never change and the whole block is unreachable...

Comment: @Jecke: The code I presented is the general idea, which seems like it should work. As for your specific concern, set `currentMoment` equal to the `StartMoment` of the first item in the viewers list. That will cause the first event to be pushed onto the EventsQueue.

Comment: But the only place where currentMoment changes is inside the `if (viewer.StartMoment > currentMoment)` block... so if I first set it to equal viewer.StartMoment, it will never reach that block of code... Unfortunately I don't really understand how this algorithm is supposed to work, so it's hard for me to debug it

Comment: @Jecke: change `int currentMoment` to `int currentMoment = Viewers[0]`, or however you get the first item in the sorted list of viewers. So the first time through the loop, the first conditional fails and this viewer gets enqueued. Then the next viewer is read (that's what `for each viewer` does). I'll add some explanation of how the algorithm is supposed to work.

Comment: @Jecke See my updated "how it works" section. I didn't say that the algorithm is simple. You will have to study it to understand the details of how it works. But perhaps my more detailed explanation will make it easier for you to get a handle on it.

Comment: thank you for explaining the code. I'm not sure if it's 100% correct (for example: you only change currentMoment to viewer.StartMoment - so if there are 5 viewers that watch the same event, all from moment 1 to moment 10, then Moments[2..9(10?)] will never be set to 5 ), but thanks to Your explanation, I managed to write a code that works (though it's still to slow - probably because of my implementation of queue): http://pastebin.com/jPDJSWML